# Restore 3D plot interactivity in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I used to be able to create interactive 3D graphs in JupyterLab using the following code, which used to work perfectly. (it is working in google colab too). However, after upgrading my environment, the interactivity is no longer functional.

```
# !pip install ipympl is necessary for google colab
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
m = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]])
x = np.arange(0,m.shape[0])
y = np.arange(0,m.shape[1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = m[X,Y]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

In the past, this code used to generate an interactive 3D wireframe graph. However, with the latest JupyterLab version (v4.0.10), it presents a static wireframe graph that lacks interactivity. I tried altering the line "%matplotlib widget" to either "%matplotlib notebook" or "%matplotlib inline", but they didn't work.

Comment: Comment on your comment on the first line: it should now be `%pip install ipympl` everywhere to install packages when running from in a cell. It works in Google Colab now, too and is the universal best way to insure the installation occurs in the correct environment where the kernel is running. As to your question, after you install `ipympl` you should be able to restart everything, kernel & browser, and use `%matplotlib ipympl` in JupyterLab. (Later I'll try to test that specifically with JupyterLab 4.1, which is the must current according to Jeremy Touloup a few days ago.)

Comment: <continued> Oops, I forgot to put that I assume by interactive, you mean it having the interactive side bar [show here in the Basic Example illustration about ipympl here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example)?

Comment: UPDATE: I just tested what I said in JupyterLab version 4.1.0b0, which is the most current version available and it worked. You can see it too, by going [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/jtpio/83b0b625cb3b6e05d7f3d8714f98182e/master) and use the session served via MyBinder.org to test it without touching your system. When it comes up, open a new cell and run `%pip install ipympl`. Let it complete & then restart the kernel and refresh your browser page. When it reloads paste in the Basic example & run it and it should look like the image [there](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example).

Comment: <continued> I forgot to say that you need to open a new notebook file before putting in `%pip install ipympl` in a cell. And I know that is the most recent version of JupyterLab because Jeremy Tuloup just announced it on December 28th and was trying to get folks to give it a spin to help catch any bugs while that version is still in 'beta'. If yours isn't behaving the way that one is with `ipympl` then there may be an issue with that particular version of JupyterLab you are using or how it is set up on your system. I guess the issue could also be in the version of `ipympl` you have.

Comment: <continued> And I just even ran your code there doing what I just said, the only difference is that I added `%matplotlib ipympl` above your line `import numpy as np` and had the rest of your code block below that in the cell I ran and it worked to give an interactive plot I can even move the view around by left-clicking and dragging.